# How to join two table with a conditon

Tags: join, plsql, conditional-statements

```
TABLO1
Inst_count    Inst_Type    Card_Group    Txn_Type    Comm_rate
----------    ---------    ----------    --------    ---------
2             N            -1            -1          1,70
2             N            36            -1          1,71
2             N            37            -1          1,72
2             V            -1            -1          1,73
2             V            36            -1          1,74
2             V            37            -1          1,75



TABLO2
Inst_count    Inst_Type    Card_Group    Txn_Type    Isk_rate    Day
----------    ---------    ----------    --------    --------    ---
2             N            -1            -1          1,0         10
2             N            36            -1          1,1         11
2             N            37            -1          1,2         12
2             V            -1            -1          1,3         13
2             V            36            -1          1,4         14
2             V            38            -1          1,5         15


Result_Table

Inst_count    Inst_Type    TABLO1.Card_Group    TABLO2.Card_Group   TABLO1.Txn_Type    TABLO2.Txn_Type    Isk_rate    Day    Comm_rate
----------    ---------    -----------------    -----------------   ---------------    ---------------    --------    ---    ---------
2             N            -1                   -1                  -1                 -1                 1,0         10     1,70
2             N            36                   36                  -1                 -1                 1,1         11     1,71
2             N            37                   37                  -1                 -1                 1,2         12     1,72
2             V            -1                   -1                  -1                 -1                 1,3         13     1,73
2             V            36                   36                  -1                 -1                 1,4         14     1,74
2             V            -1                   38                  -1                 -1                 1,5         15     1,73
2             V            37                   -1                  -1                 -1                 1,3         13     1,75
```

Inst_count and Inst_Type must be always equal.
But Card_Group and Txn_Type columns must be match in the other table with default value(-1) if not exist.
How can write this sql?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using `OUTER JOIN` which sets all your tables values into one resulset(You can also use `UNION ALL` for this purpose). Then we are using a left join for each table to make sure each column will have its values which absence of other. Now you can try this with your own query. If you can not achieve your goal then i suggest you to gather your samples into dbfiddle link. Then we can make further explanations.

```
SELECT DISTINCT NVL (A.COL1, A1.COL1) COL1A,
                NVL (B.COL1, B1.COL1) COL1B,
                NVL (A.COL2, A1.COL2) COL2,
                NVL (A.COL3, A1.COL3) COL3,
                NVL (B.COL3, B1.COL3) COL4
  FROM TABLEA A
       FULL OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON B.COL1 = A.COL1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B1 ON B1.COL1 = -1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEA A1 ON A1.COL1 = -1
```

Comment: Hocam öncelikle çok teşekkürler. Daha detaylı bir şekilde konuyu açıklamaya çalıştım yukarıda. Yorumlarını rica edeceğim :) Şimdiden teşekkürler.

Comment: If you will join these two tables only using  Card_Group and Card_Group your query will get complicated. In my example i explain how you can use sql. Check it.